# NodeJS MySQL DATE() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to get Node to query my database and send the results to the client where it is placed into a `<table>`, but with the timestamp removed from the date.

I have the following bit of Node querying my database:

```
pool.query(
    "SELECT DATE(completed), duration, submitted FROM workentries WHERE iin = ?",[iin], 
    function(error, results) {
        if(error) throw error;
        connection.release()
        res.send(results);
    }
)
```

The client-side JS:

```
const httpr = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpr.onload = () => {
    let responsej = JSON.parse(httpr.response)
    for(i in responsej) {
        document.getElementById("workentry-table").innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+responsej[i].completed+"</td><td>"+responsej[i].duration+"</td><td>"+responsej[i].submitted+"</td></tr>";
    }
}
httpr.open('GET', '/workentry-list');
httpr.send();
```

This is the result:

[image: DATE(completed) appears as undefined in the table element]

This is how the dates are formatted in the database:

[image]

I'm also going to want to reformat the timestamp on the `submitted` datetime, so it'd be a big help if I can find out how to properly format date/time for this case.

(I'm sorry if this is obvious, but I'm relatively new to Node. I Googled like a madman but couldn't find a solution, which either means this is an uncommon issue or I'm doing something stupid)

---

EDIT:

- Fixed `undefined` by using `DATE(completed) AS completed` to the query
- Fixed the date/time format by using `toLocaleString()` in the client-side

Comment: Why isn't `completed` a `DATE` column in the first place?

Comment: @Barmar It is, but it's being returned as a date followed by a 00:00:00 timestamp.

Comment: You are querying `DATE(completed)`, not `completed`. So you won't find it in `responsej[i].completed` but in `responsej[i]['DATE(completed)']`! If you don't want that, select `DATE(completed) AS completed` instead.

Comment: Also, it's not "returned as a date followed by a 00:00:00 timestamp", instead it is returned as JavaScript `Date`, and stuffing it into an HTTP response will JSON-stringify it which turns it into an ISO8601 date/time string as if you'd call `.toISOString()` on it (and this is where you get the 00:00:00). You can of course manipulate, format, etc. the `Date` in JavaScript before returning it to your client. Alternatively, you can use `DATE_FORMAT` in your SQL query to preformat it and make it return a string to you in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give an alias to the column in the `SELECT` list so you can refer to it as `responsej[i].completed`. Otherwise, you need to use `responsej[i]['DATE(completed)']`

And to format it as you want, use the `DATE_FORMAT()` function rather than returning a `DATE`.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(completed, '%Y-%m-%d') AS completed, duration, submitted FROM workentries WHERE iin = ?
```

Comment: Of course! Thank you. However, it's still returning it with a zero timestamp. Isn't `DATE()` supposed to only return the date? What's going on?

Comment: That's what it does, and it would do so even without `DATE()` because it's _already_ a `DATE` in your database. However, you are getting a JS `Date` from your MySQL driver (with the time part as midnight since there is no time information in a MySQL `DATE`) and you don't format it. Converting it to JSON (implicitly, through `res.send`) will turn it into an ISO string. See my comment on your question above.

Comment: That sounds like an issue with the way node-mysql formats date objects. You might want to use `DATE_FORMAT(completed, '%Y-%m-%d') AS completed` to format it as you want.